# Why can't i modify the text on this InDesign template?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm new to InDesign so I fully accept I'm probably doing something stupid.

[image: editing in InDesign]

I've been given a template for making an a 7x5 card. I've managed to add the images okay but when I try to edit the text either by triple clicking on it or dragging the T tool to it Im unable to select the existing 'Image Title' text for modification.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe the text is in a locked layer or even in a master page.

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @Joonas thanks you were right there were two pages, the images were on Page 1 and the text was on A-Master, by doing got page and selecting A-Master I could change it. Dont know if right template works this way.

Comment: The idea might be that you can easily make multiple versions with the same text, but different graphical elements in the background. There really aren't any standards, especially for templates.

Comment: the text will vary every time the image varies, but okay.

Comment: People who make templates of any kind have different levels of knowledge. Sometimes you see some super clever stuff and sometimes you see things that don't really make much sense... Or at all. It could just be that the person who made it had some sort of scenario in mind that he failed to share or just didn't think it through. It's hard to say without seeing it.

Comment: its okay I can work with it for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't edit text on a master page. They are for repeating elements only, and you may actually forget to include such a page in your *actual* document (in which case it will not appear in your output), or use it more than once (and you end up with two same pages).

First "apply" that master to a blank new page so all of its elements appear, then use <kbd>Cmd (or Ctrl)</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> plus a mouse double-click on the element to make a local copy on your actual page, and edit at will. InDesign will remember you 'detached' the object from a master, and the original will disappear from that one page.

If you are serious about working with InDesign, consider taking an online course (Lynda) or buy a good beginner's tutorial book (anything from Sandee Cohen for your version). (For one, they will both remind you of the proper capitalization of the trademarked name "InDesign" )

Comment: Currently Im only using inDesign one for one specific task but I wil look at a cousrse/book, I tried do what you said but failed with 'First apply that master to a blank new page so all of its elements appear' - I cant see how to do that.

Comment: @Paul: ouch. Try the online help: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/master-pages.html#apply_master_pages

Comment: Ive ordered the Sandeen book, thx for the recomendation

Comment: sidenote: @jongware I have to say Im rather disappointed in the inDesign CS6 book it basically explains whats the menu do without giving any indication of workflow or any critical appraisal of inDesign,